# SQLAlchemy gives error Exception: No searchable columns defined for model Post

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is my models.py

```
from app import db

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy_searchable import Searchable
from sqlalchemy_utils.types import TSVectorType

Base = declarative_base()

tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
)

class Post(db.Model, Base, Searchable):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    __searchable_columns = ['title', 'body']
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), index=True, unique=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(500), index=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags,
        backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))
    search_vector = db.Column(TSVectorType)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r %r>' % (self.title, self.tags)

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag %r>' % (self.name)
```

I do have the searchable columns, why is it giving this error? I couldn't find anything on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the trailing `__` on `__searchable_columns`:

```
__searchable_columns = ['title', 'body']  # Invalid
__searchable_columns__ = ['title', 'body']  # Will work
```

Comment: Thanks! Docs need to be fixed :/ http://sqlalchemy-searchable.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Ah true! :) I just noticed... but in the first code snippet the trailing __ isn't there :/

Comment: Pull request submitted to fix that :-)